# Docker compose variable substitution make a number

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use variable substitution in a `docker-compose.yml` to set the number of CPUs.

With this compose file:

**test.yml**

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.2
    cpus: ${MAX_CPUS}
```

run by this script:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export MAX_CPUS=4

docker-compose -f test.yml up -d
```

I get this error:

```
$ ./test.sh 
ERROR: The Compose file './test.yml' is invalid because:
services.neo4j.cpus contains an invalid type, it should be a number
```

The variable is being read correctly.  If use this compose file

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.2
    #cpus: ${MAX_CPUS}
    volumes:
      - ${MAX_CPUS}:/foo
```

then I get an error that uses the substituted value:

```
 ERROR: Named volume "4:/foo:rw" is used in service "neo4j" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

It appears that the variables substitution is being interpreted as a string, even though the value is a number.

Is there a way to force it to a number, assuming that is the problem?

I am running on Mac OS X using docker-machine.

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb
$ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
```

Comment: You have the `cpus` section commented out and you're using the same variable for a `volumes` definition instead, which I'm assuming you didn't mean to do - The volume "4" doesn't exist; that's where the error is coming from - and your `cpus` statement isn't even being hit.

Comment: @TJBiddle the docker-compose.yml file with the problem the OP is asking about doesn't even have a `volume` key.

Comment: @larsks Ah - you're right; I skimmed the question too quickly. Troy - why are you doing this anyhow? This ability was removed in later versions of Compose and is now only available for Swarm mode - Is there a reason why you want this in development anyhow?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am in the same situation

Comment: I don't recall finding a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the Docker Compose GitHub issues and found https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2730. It sounded very similar to your issue. It was fixed in pull request https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5291 where a type converter was added for interpolated values. It *appears* to support the `cpus` option per line https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5291/files#diff-b2372f2a81cc5911e04cc7df7d68675bR148.

However, if we take a look at the regex that has to match for the conversion at https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5291/files#diff-b2372f2a81cc5911e04cc7df7d68675bR139 we can see that it is `^0[0-9]+$`. This regular expression doesn't match single digits. But it *should* match `01`.

So, as silly as it sounds, can you try changing the number to `04` instead of `4`?

Comment: *This regular expression doesn't match single digits.* - this regex only matches numbers with leading `0`. So you can't write `16`, it has to be `016`. Sounds very strange.